# Why am I getting typerror of "RejectwithValue" is not a function

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am trying createAsyncThunk with Typescript.
On entering the catch block, I am returning rejectwithValue(param).
But on console.log(action) - I am getting error -

```
    error:
    message: "rejectWithValue is not a function"
    name: "TypeError"
    stack: "TypeError: rejectWithValue is not a function\n    at http://localhost:3000/main.105756d7251616c1b9a2.hot-update.js:35:12"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    meta: {arg: {…}, requestId: '2Z_7_5twR1VcGC2apgQcS', rejectedWithValue: false, requestStatus: 'rejected', aborted: false, …}
    payload: undefined
    type: "LOGIN_USER/rejected"
```

This is my createAsyncthunk

```
export const loginUser =  createAsyncThunk(
    types.LOGIN_USER,
    async (param : {payload : object, callback : Function},  rejectWithValue : any) : Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>> => {
        try{
            let argum : apiArgs = {
                apiUrl : '/someurl',
                method : "POST",
                payload : param.payload
            }
            const response  = await apiCall(argum)
            param.callback()
            return response.data
            
        }catch(err : any){
            return rejectWithValue(err.response.data)
        }    
    }
)
```

I am actually interested in the payload, which I am getting undefined due to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [payloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator), the second parameter of `payloadCreator` function is `thunkAPI` object which has `rejectWithValue` method.

So, it should be:

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  types.LOGIN_USER,
  async (
    param: { payload: object; callback: Function },
    { rejectWithValue }: any
  ): Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>> => {
    try {
      let argum: apiArgs = {
        apiUrl: '/someurl',
        method: 'POST',
        payload: param.payload,
      };
      const response = await apiCall(argum);
      param.callback();
      return response.data;
    } catch (err: any) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```